# getExtras from ListActivity are NULL in Android BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, null, broadcastreceiver, listactivity, extra

I'm trying to receive some data in my BroadcastReceiver which is called by a ListActivity.
It is called, I've tested it, but getExtras always returns NULL.

This is the interesting part of my ListActivity:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent distIntent = new Intent();
    distIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    distIntent.putExtra("fileName", new File("Test").getName());
    sendBroadcast(distIntent);
}
```

This is the corresponding part of my BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent){
    String b = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
    if(b != null)
        Log.e(logTag, "File Name: "+b);
}
```

The file exists, its name is added properly to the intent, but for some reason it's not propagated to my receiver.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above should work if the `new File("Test").getName()` returns a not null value.

Is the `onReceive` method called at all? I tried the code with the following `<receiver>` block in my manifest XML:

```
<receiver android:name=".TestReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And some static string instead of the getName method call and it worked.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - I just realised I used the wrong intent-filter (one to filter my custom intents) because I was testing with different actions as well.